# what is CPU family?

Tags: linux, cpu

[image]

What is the CPU family in this case? And CPU cores meens the number of cores that a prossessor has, no?

Comment: http://ark.intel.com/products/75789/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2620-v2-15M-Cache-2_10-GHz It is a 6-core + HyperThreading, btw.

Comment: About the "cpu family" :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344132/how-can-i-find-out-what-processor-family-an-intel-processor-is-under

Comment: looking up the process model name would be more educational IMO

Answer (score 5):

It's probably more worth looking up the processor as tetsujin as done - in most cases, since that gives you a bunch of information about your processor.

Family 6 indicates it's a spiritual descendant of the Pentium Pro (AKA the P6) and core families (oddly enough, they've retained that all the way from [pentium pro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_microprocessors#Pentium_Pro) - the original P6 to modern processors - with the netburst family being family 15).

In a sense, it's the microarchitectural lineage of the processor. Considering the family has been around for roughly 20 years with a short break when intel went into the space heater business with the pentium 4, It's not exactly a handy piece of information to have.

Looking up that processor, it's a hex core [processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/75789/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2620-v2-15M-Cache-2_10-GHz) with HT. Since your output shows one core - my guess would be it's a VM - so it's the number of cores allocated to the VM rather than the number of physical cores on the machine.

Answer (score 3):

`CPUID.family == 6` means it's anything from Pentium Pro (1995) to the latest Haswell (2014) except "Netburst" . For `CPUID.family == 6` you have to check the `CPUID.model` field. You can find the ranges of model numbers by painstakingly trawling through all of the various specification updates while muttering obscenities under your breath (note: this is the traditional method). I don't know if there's a less insane way of deciphering it.